# Getting value from form select option tag in Spring MVC controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I want to get my semester id value from mySQL database, for this I use  :
`<option value="${semester.id}">${semester.name}</option>`
I need to get the id as an attribute that I put in my method to get other data on this semester. For some reason, I can’t do this, most likely not the correct request in jsp. Thank you so much, please help me figure this out! I would be very grateful for any suggested solutions.

MyController for get date from database

```
   @RequestMapping("/chooseSemester")
    public String chooseSemester(@RequestParam("semId")int id,Model model){
        List<Semestr> semestr = service.getSemestr();
        model.addAttribute("semestr", semestr);
        List<Discipline> allDisciplines = service.getDisciplineSemestrId(id);
        model.addAttribute("allDisc", allDisciplines);
        return "semestr";
    }
```

JSP page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%--<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml_rt" %>--%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@page isELIgnored="false" %>

<div class="link_container">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="/home">Home</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="terms_list_container">
    <table cellspacing="0" style="margin-top: 20px">
        <tr>
            <td style="font-size: large;">Select semester</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 50px">
                <select>
                    <c:forEach items="${semestr}" var="semestr">
                            <option value="${semestr.id}">${semestr.name}</option>
                    </c:forEach>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td style="padding-left: 20px"><input type="submit"
                                                  value="Select" id="button" onclick="window.location.href = '${chooseButton}'"></td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with getting data from my jsp page is solved, the correct wrapper was needed and here is what the solution looks like:

```html
 <form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/allSemestrsSem" method="get">
            <tr>
                <td style="font-size: large;">Select semester</td>
                <td style="padding-left: 50px">

                    <select name="selectSemestr">

                        <c:forEach items="${semestr}" var="semestr">
                            <option value="${semestr.id}">${semestr.name}</option>
                        </c:forEach>

                    </select>
                </td>
                <td style="padding-left: 20px">
                    <security:authorize access="hasRole('ADMIN')">
                    <input type="submit" id="button" value="select"/></td>
                </security:authorize>
            </tr>
        </form>
```